# How can I fix this error in a web template

Tags: themes, opencart

I just installed a new theme, now I am having a problem. Whenever a customer checks out, the following error is displayed:

> Notice: Error: Could not load template
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\nowahala/catalog/view/theme/default/template/checkout/simplecheckout_shipping.tpl!
>   in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\nowahala\vqmod\vqcache\vq2-system_engine_controller.php
>   on line 75

How do i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is add the file. The error is pretty simple to understand. The template file is missing from your simple checkout. Open the modification and load the files into there (notice that it is the `default` folder)

Comment: I have searched the all the folders, no such file named simplecheckout_shipping.tpl, and if i create a blank template file, it shows a blank page on the front end

Comment: Correct, you need to add the file from the simple checkout mod that you installed previously into your default template's folders (or copy it from your custom theme folder if you moved it into there)

Comment: Hi Jay Gilford, there is no such file in either the module folder or even my theme folder

Comment: Contact the developer of SimpleCheckout. They will be able to tell you where the file is (may even be missing in the latest release)

Comment: ok, thanks for your help Jay Gildord, please i dont know how to contact him, do you know his email address? if yes, pls send it to me, thanks

Comment: Find the extension in your opencart account's order history section, and it will give you should be able to view the extension page from that. Send him a message in the comment section of the extension page